# update Eclipse PDT to php 5.5

Tags: php, eclipse, pdt

The current stable php version is 5.5.1. At Eclipse PDT we're however still stuck on 5.4. I tried updating it to the latest version but it doesn't give me any new updates. In  preferences - > PHP -> PHP Intepreter I can only select 5.4 or lower. How can I update PDT to make it interpret php 5.5?

Answer (score 3):

The Luna release has 5.5 support.

Development has slowed though. See: http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt

There are still some commits happening https://eclipse.googlesource.com/pdt/org.eclipse.pdt/
but PDT's functionality has fallen far behind PHPStorm's.

- Edited to note that Luna has support

Comment: After installing the latest nightly from http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.pdt and installing some extensions from http://p2-dev.pdt-extensions.org/ the PHP interpreter dropdown now shows PHP 5.5